# Navigating ArcObjects Object Model Diagrams (OMDs)?

Tags: arcobjects

How does everyone get round navigating the different Object Model Diagrams (OMDs)?

I can work with single interfaces no problem, but when i have to use multiple interfaces I struggle to get my head round go through different interfaces, as I am never sure which one to use.

So what is everyone's tips that they could share?

Comment: Please vote for [my idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bp9AAAQ) if you think Esri should host the OMDs in an image service.

Comment: Navigate through the co-classes. If you like an interface, find your way back to the co-class, rinse, repeat :)

Comment: The irritating thing for me is, I've been using ArcGIS for about 8'ish years, and I'm fairly good at it, but going even further under the hood is getting to me. For example, I have a hundred layers in my Data Frame, of those I want to change the transparency for the first 95, What would be your exact workflow to get get where you want to (in terms of navigating the OMD's)???

Comment: If you're using grouplayers, then you need to treat the TOC as a tree, so "first 95" would depend on the order in which you traverse it.  You might want to look at the [composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) and see how grouplayers fit into that on the Layers page of the [Carto OMD](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/Arcobjects_net/pdf/CartoObjectModel.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

Also read through the overviews for the libaries that you want to use. The overviews **should** be highlighting the most commonly used coclasses and interfaces and discuss some common workflows.

Answer (score 2):

Last time I checked there is some information found only in the OMD's, for example suppose you were writing a custom class extension.  There's a whole slew of optional interfaces to pick from, but the only place where these are nicely listed, AFAIK, is on the OMD.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It really helps if you know UML.  In the class that I had in college the professor called it QI (Query Interface) hopping.  The Getting To Know ArcObjects book has a nice break down of how to work with the diagrams.

So basically, its been sometime for me, the lollipop looking items on the left hand side of the objects define the interfaces that they implement.  Then you can use that to jump around.